# How can I "validate" DELETE request in api-platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I want to check the entity variable and check if it is allowed to delete the entity. For example if the owner entity of the association is linked to another entity, I want to make the deletion impossible.

I've looked in the documentation of api-platform bu I could not find any help regarding my problems. Either you give the right to delete or not. I could not find how to control it (equivalent to validation for POST, PUT and PATCH).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the access control feature of Api-Platform and Symfony Expression Language to achieve what you want. This way you can write pretty complex expressions.

I hope this example makes it clear.
user is the currently logged in user.
object is the resource user is trying to delete.

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *   itemOperations={
 *     "delete"={
 *       "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_USER') and object.getUsers().contains(user),
 *     }
 *   }
 * )
 */

class Entity
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="entities")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="entity_users")
     */
    private $users;

    /**
     * @return ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUsers(): ArrayCollection
    {
        return $this->users;
    }
}
```

In this case only users who are stored in users Array of Entity can delete this resource.